# I'm having problems interpreting this Java UML

Tags: java, uml, observer-pattern

[image: Part of the UML]

This is an abstract class.
what is the observers attribute? is it a List of Flyable?

I don't understand what * is here.

Comment: probably this means an array with undefined number of observers

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I didn't think about searching for the literal 'asterisk'. I only searched for 'java uml *'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flayable*` in uml means `0 to many entry`  So in java you would make it in a `ArrayList`  or any proper kind of `collection` you like then for each `Observer Flayable in you case` you will subscribe it to observe.

For further detail check Observer Pattern in Java MVC

Comment: actually, according to http://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html , it's Zero or more instances

Answer (score 1):

**[The Unified Modeling Language](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html)**

Some typical examples of multiplicity:

[image]

So, as per above table, **asterisk (*) represents zero or more Cardinality**

Comment: No. _A MultiplicityElement is unlimited if its upperBound has the UnlimitedNatural value of unlimited (“*”)_ on p. 34. It's `0..any`. The page you reference dates back to 1999!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out old reference. I have updated my answer.